# How to set cookie value with radio button?

Tags: php, javascript

How to set cookie value when user click radio button ?

#### set.php

```
   <p><strong>Please select your shipping time (optional)</strong></p>

   <div id="first">
     <input type="radio" value="9am-11am" name="shipping_time"  />9am-11am<br />
   </div>

   <div id="second">
     <input type="radio" value="11am-1pm" name="shipping_time"/>11am-1pm<br />
   </div>

   <div id="third">
    <input type="radio" value="1pm-3pm" name="shipping_time"/>1pm-3pm<br />
   </div>

   <div id="four">
    <input type="radio" value="3pm-5pm" name="shipping_time"/>3pm-5pm<br />
   </div>
```

#### view.php

```
<p><strong>Shipping time</strong> : <?php echo $_SESSION['time_shiping']; ?></p>
```

before i post, i also tried with code below, but this not solve my problem.

```
<script>
        $('#first input[type=radio]').click(function() { 
        <?php
            $_SESSION['time_shiping'] = '9am-11am';
        ?>
        });
        $('#second input[type=radio]').click(function() { 
        <?php
            $_SESSION['time_shiping'] = '11am-1pm';
        ?>
        });

        $('#third input[type=radio]').click(function() { 
        <?php
            $_SESSION['time_shiping'] = '1pm-3pm';
        ?>
        });

        $('#four input[type=radio]').click(function() { 
        <?php
            $_SESSION['time_shiping'] = '3pm-5pm';
        ?>
        });
    </script>
```

can someone show me how to set cookie with onlick function using javascript or php.

thanks.

Comment: php is server side js is client side, you don't seem to understand the difference.

Comment: yes, that why it's not work..im just try.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: I think you need to use Javascript for this one as Meisam suggests.  You can't embed PHP into your javascript, as it will be executed all at once as the page is loaded, not dynamically as you are expecting.  If you want dynamic calls made from the front-end/client to the backend/server, you need to use AJAX.

Comment: thanks, i will try with ajax submit function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set cookie, you can use following function

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = encodeURI(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString() + "; path=/");
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

setCookie('your_key', 'your_value', 'expire_time');
```

You can read this value on php side with following code

```
$_COOKIE['key_on_js_side']
```

Accoring to your code, you can refer following example;

```
$('#first input[type=radio]').click(function() { 
     setCookie('time_shipping', '9-11', 3600);
});
```

Hope it helps